# Integrate webpage in A-Frame scene

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, aframe

I want to ask, is there a method to integrate a webpage in A-Frame scene.

Like iframe tag in mormal web page.

I tried iframe tag, but it will be rendered only before the rendering of a-scene.

Thanks for any help.

Demo: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/join/b5ebb45e-cc52-4e35-8ed3-4dadfbf7cc7e

Comment: What do you mean by integrate `within` a scene?

Comment: you can always use a div tag outside of the `a-scene` tag and use absolute positioning e.g. to have a header area and footer area that works like a normal 2D page. But if you mean showing a web page within an a-scene canvas I doubt since the `canvas` tag would not support html tags

Comment: Thank you for youer help. It is maybe not possible to integrate a <html> tag to the A-Frame scene.

Comment: This is in the [A-Frame FAQ](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/faq.html#how-do-i-display-lt-iframe-gt-s-or-render-html-in-a-frame) and I also answered on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52456361/how-to-embed-a-html-page-in-webvr